# Correct .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Please, help me in this situation.

I have a shared hosting and I wanna tune my `.htaccess`file in good way.
I have following pages:

1. `index.html`
2. `news.html`
3. pages like `post-01-11-2015.html`

Now I wanna:

1. remove all `.html` at the end of all URLs
2. if current page is `index.html`, I wanna see `example.com`, not `example.com/index.html`
3. when I open `post-01-11-2015.html` in page `news.html`, I wanna see in browser URL like `example.com/posts/2015/11/01`.
4. when I enter `example.com/posts/2015/11/01` I wanna see page `post-01-11-2015.html`.
5. anything you advise me, be very good.

If you need any information, please, let me know.

Now have this module code, but I get error `cycle redirection`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
     RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]

     RewriteRule ^post-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\.html$ /posts/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L,NC]
     RewriteRule post-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\.html$ posts/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L,NC]

     RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.html [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Thank you so much! Hope you help me best way!

Answer (score 0):

Change your htaccess to:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/$ index.html [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9_-]+)/([0-9_-]+)/([0-9_-]+)/$ post-$3-$2-$1.html [QSA,L]
```